# Самый оптимальный способ сохранить много информации разных типов данных в файл

Tags: c#, bitmap, serializable, save

Допустим, есть у меня куча обьектов собственного класса. Информация включает в себя не только Int-ы, Float-ы, String-и, **но и Bitmap-ы.**

Я хочу иметь возможность все сохранить в ОДИН файл, и загрузить из файла в какой-то другой момент.

.....

Первая идея: всю текстовую инфу(или ту которую возможно перегнать в текст) сохранить в *.csv файл. Картинки засейвить просто в папку. И потом все загнать в зип-архив.

Но, уверен, возможно сделать все как-то по-проще. Например сгенерировать какую-нибуть либу в которой будут вшиты все нужные данные включая и битмапы.

**Как вообще это ЛУЧШЕ и ОПТИМАЛЬНЕЕ сделать?**

---

UPD: я запостил как ответ -- класс для удобной сериализации.

Comment: О базе данных не думали?

Comment: @Mirdin, думал, но тоже как-то сложновато. Не создавать же под каждую сессию SQLite файл. Уверен, что задача должна быть достаточно востребованная и тривиальная и решалась уже многими. Возможно, есть какой способ значительно быстрый в реализации...

Comment: Сериализация - `BinaryFormatter`. Сохранять в `GZipStream` для сжатия. Итого несколько строк кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно попросить пример?:) Звучит как именно то что мне нужно :) на примере List<T> где в <T> есть просто стринг и битмап. Тогда же  и смогу чекнуть как правильный ответ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Важно!**

`BinaryFormatter` является небезопасным в использовании и будет удалён вместе со всей инфраструктурой: [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md)

---

Смотря что подразумевать под словом "оптимальный". На выбор способа хранения влияют такие вопросы, как: каков объём сохраняемых данных, тип этих данных, нужен ли поиск в них и прочее.

Стандартным способом хранения разнотипных данных является [сериализация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/index). Она может быть в разных форматах: xml, json, бинарная. Так как у вас имеется такой тип, как `Bitmap`, то текстовые форматы плохо подходят, поэтому выберем двоичную сериализацию.

Используем класс [BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8).

Например, у нас имеется следующий класс:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public Bitmap MyBitmap { get; set; }
    public List<int> MyList { get; set; } = new List<int>();
}
```

Обратите внимание, что он помечен атрибутом [Serializable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8) - это является непременным условием для использования `BinatyFormatter`а. Также все используемые типы в нашем классе должны быть помечены этим атрибутом. Все примитивные типы в дотнете: числовые, строки - являются таковыми. Класс [Bitmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8), как можно видеть из документации, тоже помечен этим атрибутом, т. е. его тоже можно сериализовать.

Сам код сериализации/десериализации чрезвычайно прост и краток. Это можно считать "оптимальным".

```
var data = new SomeClass();
data.MyString = "foo";
data.MyBitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
data.MyList.Add(42);
data.MyList.Add(99);

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

// Запись
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Create))
using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    formatter.Serialize(zipStream, data);
}

// Чтение
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open))
using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    data = (SomeClass)formatter.Deserialize(zipStream);
}
```

И чтение, и запись осуществляются буквально парой-тройкой строк. В примере используется также и сжатие при сохранении в поток [GZipStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8) (также можно использовать [DeflateStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Именно то что искал. Есть дополнительно мелкий вопрос(возник во время доп. гугления): в каких случаях есть сенс в сериализации через внешние библиотеки, как, например, protobuf-net ?

Comment: @Andrew - "Родная" дотнетная бинарная сериализация непригодна, если нужно обмениваться данными с приложениями написанными для других платформ. А формат protobuf можно использовать и в Java, C++, Python, etc.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` [выводится](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md) из .NET, думаю в связи с этим нужно актуализировать ответ или хотя-бы добавить предупреждение.

Comment: @aepot - стоит ли переписывать все старые ответы, которым по многу лет?

Comment: Не переписывать, но хотя-бы замечание добавить. Буквально сегодня видел в комментах реф именно сюда, поэтому и открыл.

Answer (score 0):

**Важно!**

`BinaryFormatter` является небезопасным в использовании и будет удалён вместе со всей инфраструктурой: [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md)

---

к классу который будем сериализовать добавляем

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeItem
{}
```

Враппер на сериализацию:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class Serializator
{
    private static BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    
    public static void Serialize(string pathOrFileName, object objToSerialise)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            try 
            {
                _bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialise);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string pathOrFileName) 
    {
        T items;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try 
            {
                items = (T) _bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

ну и, собственно, сам пример использования:

```
List<SomeItem> itemsCollected;//list with some data

Serializator.Serialize("data.dat", itemsCollected);

var a = Serializator.Deserialize<List<SomeItem>>("data.dat");
```

В случае ошибки будет выдавать в консоль сообщение о исключении сериализации.

Comment: За два года с момента ответа, коли уж откопали свой ответ, могли бы и уже понять, что выводить ошибки в консоль в методе, который претендует на какую-то абстракцию, - крайне плохая затея)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov - не все старые ответы хочется править или не всегда есть время этим занятся)

Answer (score 0):

не забыть подключить:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
```

Comment: А то не у всех Resharper есть ;)))

Comment: этот ответ лучше внести как коментарий к любому из ответов