# Таблица рекордов WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно создать таблицу рекордов в Windows Forms. Пишу игру "Сапер".
Да так, чтобы рекорды не стирались, если закрывалась программа, и при следующем запуске можно было их просмотреть + сохранялось определенное кол-во рекордов, а последующие заменяли первые.
Связано это как-то с использованием БД или нет?

Comment: Такие данные проще всего сохранять в Xml файл.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

БД полноценная для такой задачи слишком избыточна. Даже если это SQLite -- это плохая идея создавать цедую БД ради одной таблицы в пару колонок...

Можешь пойти одним из следующих путей:

1. Сериализация бинарная - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849282/186752
2. Сохранение в CSV - [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)
3. Сохранение в INI файл. Класс для работы можно подсмотреть вот здесь: https://github.com/ukushu/DataExporter/blob/master/Ini.cs
4. Сериализация в XML

*B куча других путей, вроде сохранение в JSON, NoSQL, realm, и черти-что еще....Да хоть просто в текстовый документ в своем личном формате :)*

**Лично я бы под эту задачу выбрал бы первый путь.**

Почему:

Путь 1. - пользователи не смогут читерить вводя свои данные. Не нужно качать библиотек, не нужно подключать лишние библиотеки из "родных". Добавлять кода нужно минимум.

Путь 2. - избыточен. нужно качать левые библиотеки. Зато УДОБНО править через блокнот результаты и быть читером :)

Путь 3. - УДОБНО править через блокнот результаты и быть читером :) Так же минимум кода.

Путь 4. - Немного более сложный чем первые 3 пути. Больше кода, сложнее разбираться новичку

Comment: JSON в наше время не популярен?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да я и так слишком много накатал на такой-то вопрос... Пусть хоть с этого выберет-то)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я хоть знаю, что искать и куда смотреть.

Comment: А теперь самый важный вопрос(пожалуйста не игнорируйте): я новичок, и я не знаю как воспользоватся данной информацией. Можете подсказать куда мне нужно смотреть, чтобы понять, что там написано и воспользоватся данной информацией + получить опыт в работе с новой информацией. Если вы посоветуете вообще не лезть(да бывают такие шутники, я конечно не говорю о вас в частности, просто говорю, что были на моём опыте и такие), то знайте я очень хочу это сделать ибо я заинтересован в изучении программирования и получения результатов. И буду очень благодарен за вашу подсказку.

Comment: воспользуйся первой ссылкой. Там есть код 2х функций и примеры использования их. Будет непонятно - уточняй уже там дальше. Но попробуй разобраться самому. Окроме того не забывай голосовать за ответы в вопросах которые тебе оказались полезными и отмечать в своих вопросах "победителя"

Comment: Про лишние библиотеки в CSV вы маленько перегнули. Это же обычный текстовый формат. Кроме TextReader/Writer и String.Split ни чего не нужно для работы с ним.

Comment: @rdorn смотря что сохранять в него. В общем и целом что бы ридер полностью соответствовал спецификации формата, нужно учитывать еще что каждая из ячеек может в себе иметь знак разделителя(в случае цсв -- кома внутри самой ячейки), а так же иметь внутри код перехода на следующую строку. И тут-то оказывается что я не просто так сказал про библиотеку внешнюю, а тот путь которым ты предложил пользоваться приведет к множеству багов и изобретений велосипеда ;)

Comment: @Andrew ну перевод строки там обязан быть экранированным. А вот запятая внутри поля в кавычках вполне может быть, но это тоже решается не особо напрягаясь, так как внутренние кавычки тоже обязаны экранироваться.

Comment: C удовольствием посмотрю на простенький код, который соответствует спецификации. Пока что приведенный пример со стринг сплитом ему не соответствует :)