# c# оптимальный вариант базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

нужно вести базу клиентов. программу для запросов напишу сам. интересует вариант когда один файл базы данных и вся работа с ним. какие есть форматы базы данных и какой из них предпочтительнее?

Comment: Один файл базы данных или один сервер базы данных?  Клиентов у этой базы сколько планируется? Формат хранения вам какой нужен? Вас интересует реляционная бд? Документная? Графовая? Что хранить собрались? Какие запросы к бд хотите отправлять? Вас интересует бесплатная или платная версия бд?

Comment: @tym32167, один файл на компе, с которым будет работать прога, клиент скорее всего 1, формат хранения - не знаю, из того что успел прочитать наверно mdf,  в значениях будут string и int. запросы типичные select, add, delete, update, конечно же бесплатная

Comment: `mdf` - это файл БД Sql Server. Эту СУБД нужно устанавливать отдельно, её нельзя сделать встроенной. Да и слишком она мощная для ваших целей. Итог - не годится для вас. | От себя могу предложить либо реляционную sqlite, либо нереляционную LiteDB. А если данных немного, то вообще можно всё хранить целиком в памяти в коллекции объектов и (де)сериализовать в файл в любом удобном формате (json, xml, бинарный).

Comment: Какой объем данных планируется хранить в БД? Он может превысить 2 гигабайта?

Comment: @iluxa1810 спасибо. уже давно разобрался. выбрал Micosoft Access DB. данных несколько мб

Comment: @axmed2004 да, его я и хотел предложить. Либо, если данный ну совсем мало, то можно даже было бы в каком-нибудь XML их хранить.

Answer (score 0):

> @tym32167, один файл на компе, с которым будет работать прога, клиент скорее всего 1, формат хранения - не знаю, из того что успел прочитать наверно mdf, в значениях будут string и int. запросы типичные select, add, delete, update, конечно же бесплатная

Настоятельно советую Realm для этих целей.

Из плюсов:

- Любой SQL будет излишне сложным в написании кода и в поддержке. **С реалмом банально не нужно знать SQL языка и уметь писать оптимальные SQL запросы.** LINQ за тебя сам оптимизирует их.

  В т.ч. SQLite не лучший из вариантов, хотя в даном случае сервера ставить и не нужно.
- Realm же работает сразу с обьектами твоего языка (хоть и с некоторыми ограничениями), так что **нет нужды пользоваться ORM вообще**. У тебя не будет посредников с базой данных и не будет лишнего кода.
- Окроме того **реалм поддерживает Reactive code из коробки**, что несомненно огромнейший плюс на фоне любого SQL решения. Реализация в SQL рективности будет требовать значительно большего количества кода. Ты можешь подписыватся на изменения в таблице (или ее области) и обновлять их автоматически в куче мест твоей програмы.
- Так же реалм поддерживает [миграции баз данных из коробки](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest#migrations), что требовало бы больше кода с SQL. Что просто прекрасно, если ты наперед не знаешь структуру своей БД.
- Удобная стоковая "Realm studio" для просмотра данных твоей БД
- Ну и бесплатность (платное только использование облака)

---

Из минусов:

- неудобная поддержка коллекций (в дотнетовском реалме). -- добавление или изменение коллекции нужно делать исключительно внутри транзакции. И это все через `IList`. В других языках с этим проще. Это обусловлено ограничениями самого .Net
- огранничения в работе с LINQ. Которые тебя не коснутся вообще при маленьких базах данных. Что бы обойти ограничения просто делаешь `.ToList()` и обходишь любое ограничение. Но это путь быдлокода :)
- Realm Studio при запуске постоянно предлагает разместить БД платно в клауде. Но что поделать -- им нужно как-то зарабатывать :)
- Нужно помнить что из-за изменений в NuGet 3.1 перестали создаватся файлы с контентом из нюгетов. Так что что бы пользоватся бд нужно будет вручную создавать `FodyWeavers.xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Weavers>
      <RealmWeaver />
  </Weavers>
  ```

---

Документация:
https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest

---

**Есле таблиц буквально пара будет у тебя, то даже реалм будет излишним. Так что, вполне возможно, тебе больше подойдет [бинарная сериализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849282/186752)**

Comment: Хотел поспорить с первым абзацем, но дальше почитал и понял, что тут каждое из ваших утверждений спорное :) Сам использую SQL Server Compact, и никаких проблем, всё работает, включая миграции :)

Comment: сменил формулировки, так лучше?)

Comment: чуть получше, но, было бы наверное полезно тогда узнать не только плюшки этой realm, но и минусы. Например, как у неё дела с индексами, с ключами (в т.ч. внешними), вложенными объектами, для чего вообще этот reactive и почему его наличие - это плюс, что значит поддержка миграций "из коробки" и чем этот механизм от миграций в sql-базе отличается. Я имею ввиду, раз уж вы начали сравнивать realm с sql базами, то уж может таки поподробней опишите? Хотя такое описание для автора может и не нести никакой пользы, скорее для него это будет просто набор ключевых слов на погуглить.

Comment: ну и, есть подозрение, что эти фишки, что вы описали, они автору могут быть попросту не нужны, это как вторая причина, почему больше подробностей будет полезна автору вопроса.

Comment: @Andrew не забудьте упомянуть, что Realm не умеет делать автоинкремент первичных ключей.

Comment: @XelaNimed нечего здесь упоминать. `string Id{get;set} = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` решает эту проблему, и автоинкремент тебе не нужен. Или тебе принципиально иметь айдишник интом? Если принципиально, то почему?

Comment: Посмотрел я сайт Realm. Она же платная. Вижу только Free Trial - попробовать бесплатно. А дальше - гони денежку. Не?

Comment: Она бесплатная. Платное размещение БД у них в облаке, как я и написал в самом ответе.

Comment: Можно ссылку на офф сайте, где сказано, что она бесплатная?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 1. Реалм -- это оупенсоурс проэкт. И да, на оффсайте это написано. Ты веришь в то, что у платной библиотеки будет открытый код? Хотя бы один пример такой ситуации дать можешь? 2. зайди в прайсинг и посмотри за что там можно платить. Только за клауд и за саппорт. Окроме клауда и саппорта там нечего оплачивать ибо это опенсорс. Вот на это Free Trial тебе и предлагают. 3. Я сам пользуюсь реалмом. Я знаю про что говорю, когда говорю что он бесплатный.