# Сериализация c# MongoDB

Tags: c#, сериализация

Нужно сериализовать класс, не знаю как это реализовать.
Класс Person:

```
class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id;
        public string Name;
        public int Attack;
        public int Defense;
    }
```

Сериализатор:

```
public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Person person)
        {
            if (person == null)
            {
                context.Writer.WriteNull();

            }
            else
            {
                context.Writer.WriteStartDocument();
                context.Writer.WriteName("_id");
                context.Writer.WriteObjectId(person.Id);
                context.Writer.WriteName("Name");
                BsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Writer, person.Name, null, args);
                context.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }

        }
```

Как его использовать, не подскажите? Как документ с помощью него в БД?

Comment: Можешь использовать бинарную стерилизацию. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849282/186752

Comment: Да я и так уже стерилизован, мне бы сериализацию узнать как сделать.

Comment: спасибо, поржал) Ну, ты понял)