# Как раскодировать бинарный файл и занести данные в две переменные?

Tags: c#

У меня есть бинарный файл в который я записал две переменные(string и int). Мне нужно вытащить их оттуда и записать в класс. Я написал часть кода но он не работает правильно.
Вот мой код:

```
static Product ReadProduct(string fname)
    {
        Product product = new Product(" ", 0);

        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] strBytes = new byte[sizeof(char)];
            f.Read(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
            {
                f.Read(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
                string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(strBytes);

                if (str != " ")
                {
                    product.Name += str;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            byte[] priceBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            f.Read(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
            product.Price = BitConverter.ToInt32(priceBytes, 0);

        }
        return product;
    }
```

Мой код считывает файл и записывает его, но на выводе я вижу неправильные символы.

Код записи в файл:

```
static void WriteProduct(Product product,string fname)
    {
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] strBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(product.Name);
            f.Write(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);

            byte[] slashn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\n");
            f.Write(slashn, 0, slashn.Length);

            byte[] priceBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(product.Price);
            f.Write(priceBytes, 0, priceBytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Вот вывод:
M i l k
жяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя
0

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите код записи в файл.

Comment: Вы когда читаете - промежуточный вывод делайте и проверяйте на каждом этапе f.Read/Write, что и как прочиталось/записалось. Trace.WriteLine никто использовать не запрещает.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 0):

Используя код с ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849282/186752

можно сделать так:

```
var prod = new Product("SomeProduct", 0);

//сохраняем
Serializator.Serialize("prod.dat", prod);

//загружаем из файла
var a = Serializator.Deserialize<Product>("prod.dat");
```

не забываем еще о том что сам продукт должен быть Serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{}
```

Comment: Забыть про `BinaryFormatter` раз и навсегда, нет его больше в .NET.